# How to rotate a div using hammer.js 2.0.4

Tags: rotation, hammer.js

I am trying to rotate a div using hammer.js v2.0.4

HTML

```html
<div class="trans-circle" id="circleDiv">
  <div class="border-circle">
    <div class="large-circle">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br/><br/> Amirzai Sangin<br/>Minister of Communications<br/> Afghanisthan</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mini-circles1">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. <br/><br/> John Campbell<br>President and CEO<br> Toranto Waterfront Revitalization Corportation</p>
    </div>                
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```js
var trans = document.getElementById('circleDiv');
var tra = new Hammer(trans);

tra.get('rotate').set({ enable: true });

rev.on("rotate", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    alert('rotated');

});
```

But the div is not rotating, Any thing wrong am doing here?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo "**rev**" when defining your rotate function.
It should applied to **tra** and not rev. (or else tra should be named rev, which ever way.)

See a corrected version below. Check the line `tra.on("rotate", function....`

```js
var trans = document.getElementById('circleDiv');
var tra = new Hammer(trans);

tra.get('rotate').set({ enable: true });

tra.on("rotate", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
  alert('rotated');
});
```

And dont forget to add the hammer.js library :

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tested it on jsfiddle. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/vw1cs9du/2/    Your code should just pop an alert box with the word rotated.

Comment: What device are you using for testing ?

Comment: Am testing in my desktop chrome browser with device mode enabled

Comment: does the div rotated in your testing?

Comment: no. it just does **alert('rotated');** It's what you have in your code. :-)

Comment: I am using hammer.js v2.0.4 and have added the library :-)

Comment: and you get the alert box ?

Comment: No, how did you rotated the div? are you using touch monitor? did you rotated with two fingers?

Comment: I tried with 2 fingers , testing on a samsung phone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68218/discussion-between-rtome-and-vamsi).

Answer (score 0):

The relevant event property is `event.rotation`.